# Using anytree to convert JSON to a image

Tags: python, json, anytree

I am trying to use anytree to read a JSON file and export it as a png image using render tree graph. For a basic example where I create the node it works.

```
from anytree import RenderTree
from anytree import Node
from anytree.dotexport import RenderTreeGraph

root = Node("root")
s0 = Node("s0", parent=root)
s1 = Node("s1", parent=root)
t1 = Node("t1", parent=s0)

print(root)
RenderTreeGraph(root).to_picture("test.png")
```

[image: Image generated by program]

When I try importing a json file as per the [docs](https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/importer/jsonimporter.html)

```
from anytree.importer import JsonImporter
from anytree import RenderTree
from anytree import Node
from anytree.dotexport import RenderTreeGraph
importer = JsonImporter()
path = open("config.json")

root = importer.read(path)
tree = RenderTree(root)
print(tree)

RenderTreeGraph(tree).to_picture("test.png")
```

I get the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyth.py", line 20, in <module>
    DotExporter(tree).to_dotfile("tree.dot")
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/anytree/exporter/dotexporter.py", line 214, in to_dotfile
    for line in self:
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/anytree/exporter/dotexporter.py", line 160, in __iter
    for node in self.__iter_nodes(indent, nodenamefunc, nodeattrfunc):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/anytree/exporter/dotexporter.py", line 174, in __iter_nodes
    nodename = nodenamefunc(node)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/anytree/exporter/dotexporter.py", line 142, in __default_nodenamefunc
    return node.name
AttributeError: 'RenderTree' object has no attribute 'name'`

Piping the `print(tree)` to a text file give the JSON as a text block without white space formatting, where as in the docs this needs to be done line by line to capture the tree structure. So it appears as though `RenderTree(root)` isn't formatting the JSON in the Node style of the first example.

Does anyone know what is going wrong? Is there another step to correctly parse the JSON?

Comment: Do you still want an answer ?

Comment: Yeah, still a useful thing to be able to do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make a generalized example, i.e. where you almost have nothing to do manually.

***Imports***

```
import anytree.exporter as atex
import anytree as at
import json
```

***A JSON***

Below *(i)* `a_str_json`, a toy-json that I found at https://json.org/example.html, and which is representative of the content of your file called `"config.json"` and *(ii)* `a_dict`, its python converted version.

```
a_str_json = ("""
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
""")

a_dict = json.loads(a_str_json)
```

***Core job***

Let's define `tree_builder`, a function that will build our tree by exploring `a_dict` recursively.

```
def tree_builder(d, p_uid='root', l=0):

    for i, (k, v) in enumerate(d.items()):
        node_uid = 'l{}n{}'.format(l, i)
        node = nodes[k] = at.Node(
            name   = node_uid,
            key    = k,
            parent = nodes[p_uid]
        )
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            node.an_attr = ''
            tree_builder(v, k, l + 1)
        else:
            node.an_attr = v
```

... and use it

```
root  = at.Node(name='root', key='root', an_attr='')
nodes = {'root' : root}
tree_builder(a_dict)

for pre, fill, node in at.RenderTree(root):
    print("%s%s|%s" % (pre, node.key, node.an_attr))

atex.DotExporter(
    root, nodeattrfunc = lambda n : 'label="{}\n{}"'.format(n.key, n.an_attr)
).to_picture("root.png")
```

which produces

```
root|
└── glossary|
    ├── title|example glossary
    └── GlossDiv|
        ├── title|S
        └── GlossList|
            └── GlossEntry|
                ├── ID|SGML
                ├── SortAs|SGML
                ├── GlossTerm|Standard Generalized Markup Language
                ├── Acronym|SGML
                ├── Abbrev|ISO 8879:1986
                ├── GlossDef|
                │   ├── para|A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.
                │   └── GlossSeeAlso|['GML', 'XML']
                └── GlossSee|markup
```

and

[image]

---

***Tested*** with GraphViz 2.38 under windows 10.

Comment: That appears to work, except I am not seeing the image even if I give it a compete file path to save to. (I am on windows, don't know if that makes a difference).

Comment: Errors with can't find the file specified

Comment: My code is on a folder within my user area. Trace on paste bin.

https://pastebin.com/fzhFHUrg

Comment: Ahhh, OK. I was unable to install python-graphviz, that could be it.

Comment: @MikeS159 No. Do not use python-graphviz. Download directly GraphViz from [here](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html) and do not forget to [add](https://youtu.be/bEroNNzqlF4) its bin folder (for example `C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin`) to the path.